# LINQ Grouping by ParentId

Tags: c#, linq

I have a seemingly simple task that I am having far more trouble than I care to admit doing. I have a hierarchical table that I need to query and display the results grouped by the parent with associated children.

My current LINQ query:

```
var quests = Questions.Include(q => q.Question2)
      .Include(q => q.Sections)
      .Include(q => q.QuestionType)
      .Include(q => q.AnswerOptions)
      .Where(sq => sq.Sections.Any(s => s.SectionId == sectionId))
      .OrderBy(q=> q.QuestionId).ThenBy(q => q.ParentQuestionId);
```

This produces a result set of:

[image]

What I want to produce is:

[image]

My Question is simply, how can I get the desired results using Lambda syntax.

Comment: Is the Order the only difference I see?

Comment: Does `OrderBy(q => q.ParentQueryId).ThenBy(q => q.QuestionId)` get you what you want?

Comment: Thank you Servy for adding in the images. I don't have enough rep yet. :)

Comment: @matt-dot-net yes order is really the only thing that matters for this one.

Comment: Isn't Linqpad awesome?

Comment: So it looks like you essentially have a tree structure here.  Is that tree always of depth 2, or does it go arbitrarily deep?

Comment: in this case it is always a depth of 2, but could go beyond that if needed.

Comment: @MikeRamsey So you need to support having a depth of 3, 4, or N, you won't always have a depth of 2 as you do in this case here, or you just don't care if someone does that for you?

Comment: Yes at some point i will need to allow for multiple depths, but for now 2 will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update based on Servys' comment.

First line is to make sure all related questions are grouped together.
Second line is to make sure parent question is first.
Third line is to order properly

```
 .OrderBy(q => q.ParentQuestionId == null ? q.QuestionId : q.ParentQuestionId)
 .ThenBy(q => q.ParentQuestionId == null ? 0 : 1)
 .ThenBy(q => q.DisplayOrder);
```

Comment: By the look of it this may work for the OP's specific data, but isn't solving the root problem as it's relying on assumptions that may not hold.  Note he's essentially trying to build a tree in which each child follows it's parents or older siblings.

Comment: @Servy - you are correct.. while this does serve the quick fix, it may break once the tree structure grows to multiple levels. I am ok with the quick fix for now. I appreciate all the help!

Comment: The updated answer helps even further... Thanks.. as soon as i can accept the answer, I will.

Comment: @MikeRamsey - I am glad that I could help

Answer (score 3):

So it seems what you're really trying to create here is a tree based structure in which, at the top level, you have all questions with no parent, and then as "child" nodes all questions that have that as a parent.

```
var questions = GetAllQuestions();//here is where you can put your includes, etc.

var query = questions.Where(q => q.ParentQuestionId != null)
    .GroupBy(q => q.ParentQuestionId)
    .Select(group => new
    {
        Parent = questions.First(q => q.QuestionId == group.Key),
        Children = group.OrderBy(q => q.DisplayOrder),
    })
    .OrderBy(group => group.Parent.DisplayOrder);
```

Comment: I am accepting the quick fix answer, but yours is quite future proof. Thank you for the prompt help!

Answer (score -1):

```
.OrderBy(x => (x.ParentQuestionId==null?x.QuestionId:x.ParentQuestionId.Value));
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to produce what the desired results shows.  Notice question 265.

Comment: yeah i tried that as you and steaks suggested but it doesn't help. thanks.